# SQL trigger on one field

Tags: sql, database, triggers, sqlite, relational-database

I have a table with many fields/columns and I wanted to create a trigger to update an a cell labeled 'evaluation_date' when another specific cell in the row/record (the cell labeled 'comment') is updated. Below is what I have done

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trig AFTER UPDATE ON MYTABLE
BEGIN
  update MYTABLE SET evaluation_date = datetime('now') WHERE comment = NEW.comment;
END;
```

But what is happening is when any field in the row is update the evaluation_date is changing/being updated. That's not what is desired, I want evaluation_date updated only when the 'comment' cell is updated. How can that be? I am using SQLITE3 database. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SQLite syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) you may specify column for your trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_trig AFTER UPDATE OF comment ON MYTABLE
BEGIN
    update MYTABLE SET evaluation_date = datetime('now') WHERE comment = NEW.comment;
END;
```